# Key "`" is inverted with "<" on Apple Aluminium Keyboard (ISO)

Tags: 22.04, apple-keyboard

On Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 I fixed this issue with simply

```
setxkbmap -option apple:badmap
```

This option doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04.

Anybody solved this?

Comment: setxkbmap only works with xorg, not Wayland, and 22.04 uses Wayland by default. You can try gnome-tweak-tools though, and see if keyboard tweak you need is listed there. Or you can modify the keyboard mapping files manually, or you can switch to xorg.

Comment: Thank you for hints. gnome-tweak-tools used to have "Gnome Tweak Tool/Typing/Miscellaneous compatibility options/Apple Aluminium Keyboard: emulate PC (Print, Scroll Lock Pause, Num Lock)" in previous versions. Latest version installed is "42~beta-1ubuntu1" which doesn't have this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found a solution after much research:

1. Go to **Ubuntu Software**.
2. Install **Input Remapper** app.
3. Open the app.
4. On **Device** select your keyboard.
5. Click on **New entry**.
6. Click on **Change Key** (make sure it now shows **Press key**).
7. On your keyboard, press the key you want to replace (in my case "<" key).
8. Under **Change Key** button, write the name of key to replace with (in my case "less").
9. Click on **New entry**.
10. Click on **Change Key** (make sure it now shows **Press key**).
11. On your keyboard, press the key you want to replace (in my case "º" key).
12. Under **Change Key** button, write the name of key to replace with (in my case "masculine").
13. On **Rename** write a name for the preset and click on the green arrow.
14. Click on **Apply**.
15. **Important!** Click on **Autoload**.
16. Enjoy!

[image: Input Remapper configuration]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Your solutions works.

FYI I did code review. This is Python Daemon which hooks to file descriptor listens to keystrokes and replaces them in place. So basically your keyboard is relying on one Python process, which has multithreading but with GIL (global instance lock), although code is written using asyncio. 

I will search for more advanced solution. Something like this but as eBPF :-) 

P.S. Thank you soo much for this!

Comment: You're welcome! For me, as long as it works, it's OK :)